# MySQL Tables Arrangement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, security, data-storage

I have a corporate website which is used to communicate between staff members as well as staff members with clients. There are **internal users** who can login and work with their mail using web interface, there is a list of **external clients** with email address and phone numbers which internal users can use to write an email or make a call. Sometimes clients become staff members, sometime staff members gets fired but stays in the database as they can become future clients.

There are two MySQL tables for those two types. First one is a full list of all **people**, and there is a separate table of internal **users** partially **duplicating** the first table. The second table for the people who can login so it has login, password and some permisisons fields but it also have last name, first name, job, address etc. which is already in the first table.

So all internal users have two entries - one entry at the **users table** and one at **people table**. People table has internal users and all the external clients data.

I'm thinking to make one table from those two just by **adding internal users fields to the people table** such as login, password, permissions etc. so whoever have those fields filled considered to be internal users. That would probably simplify my SQL queries and get rid of edless SQL JOIN constructions as I constantly have to fetch data from both of the tables in order to get full data on a user.

Basically **I want users table to become part of the people table**. Is there any negative consequences per your experience may be in terms of **security** or **conviniency** that can be a problem for such an integration of clients and users being put together in one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should get rid of the `users` table.  The distinction between internal and external users is too important to depend just on the use of columns.

Instead, make `users` a "subtype" of `people`.  So keep the `people` table and include all the users in them, with the appropriate "people" fields.  Then in your `users` table, include the internal information along with a `people` id.

With this structure, it is easy to get "everyone" (from `people`) and "internal users" (from `users`).  To get external users, you need to do something like:

```
select p.*
from people p
where not exists (select 1 from users u where p.personid = u.personid);
```

This should be a fast operation, with a index on `personid`.  You could maintain a flag in the `people` table, indicating whether someone is or is not a person, but you would need a trigger to keep it up-to-date.  Probably not worth the effort.